# Why Riemannian metric does not depend on the choice of coordinate system

Tags: proof-verification, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In DoCarmo’s *Riemannian Geometry* book, a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold $M$ is defined to be a correspondence which associates to each point $p$ of $M$ an inner product $<,>_p$ on the tangent space $T_pM$ such that if $x:U\subset\mathbb R^n\rightarrow M$ is a coordinate system around $p$, with $x(x_1,...,x_n)=q\in x(U)$, then $g_{i,j}(x_1,...,x_n):=<dx_q(e_i),dx_q(e_j)>_q$ is a smooth function on $U$.

Now I want to prove that this definition does not depend on the choice of coordinate system. So suppose $y:V\rightarrow M$ is another coordinate system around $p$. We have $<dy_q(e_i),dy_q(e_j)>_q=<dx_q(d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_i)),dx_q(d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_j))>_q$, and since the terms $d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_i)$ and $d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_j)$ are smooth linear combinations of the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n$ as a map of $q$, using the bilinearity of the inner product and our hypothesis about the coordinate system $x$, we deduce the same for the coordinate system $y$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I don't understand. What is $\langle dx_p(e_i),dx_p(e_j)\rangle $?

Comment: They are notations used in that book. $dx_p$ means the differential of the map $x$ at p, and $e_i$ is the i’th standard coordinate vector of $\mathbb R^n$. @Dog_69

Comment: But then $dx_p(e_i)$ is a scalar. It does not make sense to consider the scalar product of two scalars.

Comment: No it’s a vector, because $dx_p$ maps vectors to vectors @Dog_69

Comment: Yes, it is true. I was thinking of $dx^i$. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have not intepreted the question correctly (or at least you have left too many words out that I cannot tell whether you have interpreted it correctly).

In particular, I do not see that you have actually used the definition of a smooth manifold, in particular you have not made use of the key fact about smooth manifolds, namely smoothness of overlap maps. You write about two coordinate systems $x$ and $y$, and you mention the overlap $x^{-1} y$, but you never mention or make use of the key fact that the overlap maps $x^{-1} y$ and $y^{-1} x$ are smooth.

Let me separate the definition of a Riemannian metric on $M$ into two parts:

1. The object given;
2. The property that object must satisfy.

The object given is:

> The correspondence which associates to each point $p \in M$ an inner product $\langle,\rangle_p$ on the tangent space $T_p M$".

Up to here, coordinate systems are *not* involved, but now they come into the property that the correspondence must satisfy:

> If $x:U\subset\mathbb R^n\rightarrow M$ is a coordinate system around $p$, with $x(x_1,...,x_n)=q\in x(U)$, then $g_{i,j}(x_1,...,x_n):=<dx_q(e_i),dx_q(e_j)>_q$ is a smooth function on $U$.

The issue is whether *this property* depends on the coordinate system.

What one must show is if $y:V\rightarrow M$ is another coordinate system around $p$, and if we let $h_{i,j}(y_1,...,y_n) := \langle dy_q(e_i),dy_q(e_j) \rangle_q$, then on the overlap $U \cap V$, to say that each of the functions $g_{i,j} \mid x(U \cap V)$ is smooth is equivalent to saying that each of the functions $h_{i,j} \mid y(U \cap V)$ is smooth.

The way you prove this equivalence is to write out how to relate the maps $g_{i,j} \mid x(U \cap V)$ and $h_{i,j} \mid y(U \cap V)$ (for each $i,j$) are related, expressing this relation as a equation obtained from the chain rule, involving the Jacobian matrices for the overlap maps $x^{-1} y$ and $y^{-1} x$.

Comment: In my statement “$<dy_q(e_i),dy_q(e_j)>_q=<dx_q(d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_i)),dx_q(d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_j))>_q$, and since the terms $d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_i)$ and $d(x^{-1}y)_q(e_j)$ are linear combinations of the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n$, using the bilinearity of the inner product and our hypothesis about the coordinate system $x$, we deduce the same for the coordinate system $y$.”, by linear combinations of coordinate vectors I mean a sum of Javobian elements of $d(y^{-1}x)_q$ multiplied by corresponding coordinate vectors, and it’s a smooth linear combination depending on $q$.

Comment: Am I clear? I think I basically meant what you have written

Comment: With that extra explanation, I can see that perhaps you did have the correct explanation in mind. That extra wording is quite important, it makes explicit what is the most important point, namely the smoothness of the overlap maps.